# How to integrate solr search in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, solr

How to do SOLR autocomplete search box with codeigniter?
Please tell me any one
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This link have tutorial and code to implement SOLR in Codeigniter. Then you have to do auto-complete yourself with help of ajax and jquery.

http://mayeul.com/apache-solr-with-codeigniter/

**Edit:**
Unfortunately above link was broken. 
I found something new but not for codeigniter. This github link have whole source code and you can create CI library or helper from this package.

https://github.com/basdenooijer/solarium

Comment: Thanks,I downloaded solr class from http://mayeul.com/apache-solr-with-codeigniter/ and place the files according to structure.Now how to use it?.how to connect with db? where can i create schema.xml?please explain clearly.

Comment: No need to connect db again. It will be taken from CI db instance.

Comment: I get the following code from http://mayeul.com/apache-solr-with-codeigniter/                                                           $this->load->library('solr');
 $val=$this->solr->select()
 ->from('table_name')
 ->where('FNAME', 'value')      
 ->order_by('order', 'ASC')
 ->limit(10);
 
 $arrSolr = $this->solr->qAssoc();
 print_r($arrSolr);                Now where can i place this code ?

Comment: this is just sample code. For auto comoplete, you have to write this code in controller. Then trigger ajax call when type something in text box. Get ajax response and populate in suggestion list.

Comment: Ya,i developed normal auto complete by using jquery,ajax.In that i get ajax call data in my controller and send it to model and get data like user entered data and displayed it.                                                         Same process how to implement with solr?I am succeed upto getting user entered value in my controller through ajax call.Now (instead of sending data to model) what can i do here?      Please explain.                                                     Thanks for your response

Comment: Link was not working, Is there any other links for integrating solr with codeigniter. Help me please.

Comment: @Mahendra.. most of Links related with SOLR are not available. I'm searching some good article to post. Thanks

Comment: @kumar_v Yea I too got same issue, many of the links are not working related to SOLR. If you find any useful link could you please send me. Thank you!.

Comment: @kumar_v link is not working

Comment: @RakeshShetty.. Sorry rakesh.. there is no active link available right now. Will update with relevant details soon.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20862421)

Comment: @Prajwal updated link. this is not simple to provide snippet based solution. So i linked link here.